# What does "on one hand" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

There is no "on the other hand" here. So what does it mean when used alone?

"**On one hand**, Mr. Draghi seemed to be stating the obvious. But among traders and investors, the statement crystallized expectations that the end of quantitative easing was near."

Source: https://www.nytimes.com/2017/07/20/business/ecb-draghi-rates-quantitative-easing.html?ref=business

Comment: Look it up in a dictionary – where does it say it must be paired with *on the other hand*?

Comment: It's rhetorically sloppy (it ought to be paired with "on the other hand" instead of "but"), but that's a quibble of style. It still means the same thing without the other hand.

Comment: The second sentence starts with "But" which provides "the other hand". I agree that this is question of style. I don't see any issue with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no "on the other hand" here. So what does it mean when used alone?

Nothing different.  Sometimes "on the other hand" is implied and not expressed in following sentences.  Especially if the next sentence starts with a subordinating conjunction like that

You will also find "on the other hand" specified without an initial "on one hand."